# How can I print an html list in two columns just using markup and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a list, `ul` or `ol`, with n list items (`li`s), how can I convert this list into a two independent column list items by just using CSS & html?

Comment: Need more info...are these lists dynamically generated?  What does the code look like?

Comment: I have a list, a typical run of the mill array with arbitrary number of items, need to display them in `li` or `ul` in two columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by floating the `li`s, and forcing them to have a width of 50%:

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KzCxh/

Comment: Just to note, this will give you an odd/even pattern where all the odd numbered bullets are in column 1 and even number bullets are in column 2. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KzCxh/1/

Comment: @michael, then in that case I shall not use `ol`, `ul` will work fine for me and thanks Arnaud :-)

Comment: I just meant that it will split the list by one left, one right type thing, not that it had to be a numbered list. If you want to have it split like the top half and bottom half, you would have to do it a different way (CSS3 is the only way I can think off without javascript).

Comment: @michael, in this case, life is bit simpler for me :-) till the time I see a CR

Comment: @Kumar, that's because you replaced the `ul` with a `ol`, but the css applies to the `ul` only ;)

Answer (score 3):

At this point, not in the way you probably want to, at least not reliably cross-browser. It is easy to make it two columns where the list would look like:

```
record 1    record 2
record 3    record 4
```

To do that you would just float each `li` left.

Someday you'll be able to do it across browsers - [it is coming in CSS3.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you know exact widths something like this will work quite well:

```
ul{
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;  
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/4HQT8/)

Comment: arnaud has a better solution :)